# How to delete the embedded picture and add lyrics in flac?

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, flac

According to [FLAC Documentation](https://xiph.org/flac/format.html#metadata_block_picture), pictures can be stored in flac audio format, but lyrics (maybe lrc, srt, or even ass/ssa) isn't mentioned in that documentation.

So, how to delete the embedded picture from flac and add lyrics into flac by software run in Linux platform?

(FFmpeg/avconv are preferred.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that the embedded artwork is in a flac standard PICTURE block then:

```
metaflac --remove --block-type=PICTURE flacfile.flac
```

...ought to do it.

If the artwork is in the old, non-standard b64 encoded format, then:

```
metaflac --remove-tag=COVERART flacfile.flac
```

..ought to do it. No idea about the lyrics though.

[Source](http://www.hydrogenaud.io/forums/index.php?showtopic=61001)

Relevant: http://linux.die.net/man/1/metaflac

Answer (score 0):

You can use metaflac to add lyrics as well.  Assume that the lyrics to "Tomorrow Never Knows" are in file "2-06.lyrics":

```
$ ls
'Grateful Dead -- 2-06 - Tomorrow Never Knows.flac'   2-06.lyrics

$ metaflac --remove-tag="Lyrics" "Grateful Dead -- 2-06 - Tomorrow Never Knows.flac"

$ metaflac --set-tag-from-file="Lyrics=2-06.lyrics" "Grateful Dead -- 2-06 - Tomorrow Never Knows.flac" 

$ metaflac --show-tag="Lyrics" "Grateful Dead -- 2-06 - Tomorrow Never Knows.flac" |more
Lyrics=Turn off your mind, relax
and float down stream
--More--
```

If you want to paste the lyrics into the terminal via STDIN (e.g., after a web search) followed by [CTRL-D]:

```
$ metaflac --set-tag="Lyrics=$(cat -)" "Grateful Dead -- 2-06 - Tomorrow Never Knows.flac"
[paste lyrics]
^D
```

NB: You can do this in ffmpeg too.
To read from file 2-06.lyrics:

```
$ ffmpeg -y -i "Grateful Dead -- 2-06 - Tomorrow Never Knows.flac" -codec copy -metadata "Lyrics=$(cat lyrics)" "~Grateful Dead -- 2-06 - Tomorrow Never Knows.flac"
$ mv "~Grateful Dead -- 2-06 - Tomorrow Never Knows.flac" "Grateful Dead -- 2-06 - Tomorrow Never Knows.flac"
```

If you want to paste the lyrics into the terminal via STDIN followed by [CTRL-D]:

```
$ ffmpeg -y -i "Grateful Dead -- 2-06 - Tomorrow Never Knows.flac" -codec copy -metadata "Lyrics=$(cat -)" "~Grateful Dead -- 2-06 - Tomorrow Never Knows.flac" 
[paste lyrics]
^D
$ mv "~Grateful Dead -- 2-06 - Tomorrow Never Knows.flac" "Grateful Dead -- 2-06 - Tomorrow Never Knows.flac"
```

If you wanted to tag an entire directory, you could put that in a for loop:

```
$ for f in *flac; do metaflac --remove-tag="Lyrics"; printf 'Paste lyrics for %s followed by Control-D:\n' "$f"; metaflac --set-tag="Lyrics=$(cat -)" "$f"; done
```

Comment: [beets can ostensibly autotag lyrics to files](https://beets.readthedocs.io/en/v1.6.0/plugins/lyrics.html).  
**YMMV**: I'm here because I have to go back and correct a number of songs.